# Converting list elements to sublists in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list `G3`. I am performing permutation of all list elements and creating another list `A`. But I want each element of ``A``` to be a sublist as shown in the expected output below.

```
import itertools
G3=[[0, 4, 5]]
A=list(itertools.permutations(G3[0], 2))
print(A)
```

The current output is

```
[(0, 4), (0, 5), (4, 0), (4, 5), (5, 0), (5, 4)]
```

The expected output is

```
[[0, 4], [0, 5], [4, 0], [4, 5], [5, 0], [5, 4]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map). With `map`, The functionality is applied to each element in the list.

```
A = list(map(list, itertools.permutations(G3[0], 2)))
# Like 'list comprehension'
A = [list(arr) for arr in itertools.permutations(G3[0], 2)]
print(A)
```